# How to enable audio controls in multitasking bar for app that uses AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, multitasking

Our music app uses AVAudioPlayer to play music. But in background, the multitasking bar does not show play/pause/stop controls to control audio of our app. Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use this class:

[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you have specific questions about it, just ask.